# iCheck check if checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, icheck

I am using iCheck plugin for customizing checkboxes. I need to display certain text when **one or more** checkbox is checked and hide the text when none are checked.

The code I have currently displays the text on first click but doesn't hide it unless I click 2 more times. 
I have multiple checkboxes and would like to show text if one of 'em are checked else hide the text.
Does anybody have any idea? The plugin has:

```
ifChecked
ifChanged
ifClicked
ifUnchecked
ifToggled
ifDisabled
ifEnabled.......
```

callbacks....Here is the plugin function

```
$('input').iCheck({ 
checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-blue',
radioClass: 'iradio_square-blue',
increaseArea: '20%' // optional
});
```

Here is what I tried..

```
$('input').on('ifChecked', function(event){
$(".hide").toggle();
});
```

html

```
<input type="checkbox">
<div class"hide" style="display:none">Hi there</div>
```

Comment: This might give you some direction `:)` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660323/jquery-checkboxes-and-ischecked P.S. Post is bit convoluted thought I will paste the `is(':checked')` flag so that you can use it accordingly. flick a jsfiddle I should be able to help you.

Answer (score 64):

For those who struggle with this:

```
const value = $('SELECTOR').iCheck('update')[0].checked;
```

This directly returns `true` or `false` as `boolean`.

Comment: what need to be pass in place of *SELECTOR* here ?

Comment: it's a jquery selector for example if you want to select a class you need to use `.myClass` if you want to select an id then you should use `#myID`

Comment: Thanks, this way is also working when checking the input with jquery!

Comment: for me return undefined. `TypeError: Cannot read property 'checked' of undefined`

Comment: @SercanOzdemir Man you are awesome (y)

Answer (score 34):

you can get value of checkbox and status by

```
$('.i-checks').on('ifChanged', function(event) {
    alert('checked = ' + event.target.checked);
    alert('value = ' + event.target.value);
});
```

Answer (score 21):

Check this :

```
var checked = $(".myCheckbox").parent('[class*="icheckbox"]').hasClass("checked");

if(checked) {
  //do stuff
}
```

Comment: This does not work well.
I am collecting the `checked`class state of a lot of iCkeck-boxed, but the code that sets the `check` class is slower than my specific code that reads the class.
Thus this method has timing issues and should be avoided.

Answer (score 15):

All callbacks and functions are documented here: http://fronteed.com/iCheck/#usage

```
$('input').iCheck('check'); — change input's state to checked
$('input').iCheck('uncheck'); — remove checked state
$('input').iCheck('toggle'); — toggle checked state
$('input').iCheck('disable'); — change input's state to disabled
$('input').iCheck('enable'); — remove disabled state
$('input').iCheck('indeterminate'); — change input's state to indeterminate
$('input').iCheck('determinate'); — remove indeterminate state
$('input').iCheck('update'); — apply input changes, which were done outside the plugin
$('input').iCheck('destroy'); — remove all traces of iCheck
```

Answer (score 13):

You just need to use the callbacks, from the documentation:
https://github.com/fronteed/iCheck#callbacks

```
$('input').on('ifChecked', function(event){
  alert(event.type + ' callback');
});
```

Comment: how the hell is this responding to the quetion?

The question was clear how to determine if the checkbox is checked or not, not what `type` of event was raised!!

Answer (score 10):

To know if the iCheck box is checked

```
var isChecked = $("#myicheckboxid").prop("checked");
```

Answer (score 7):

I wrote some simple thing:

When you initialize `icheck` as:

```
$('input').iCheck({
    checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-blue',
    radioClass: 'iradio_square-blue',
    increaseArea: '20%' // optional
});
```

Add this code under it:

```
$('input').on('ifChecked', function (event){
    $(this).closest("input").attr('checked', true);          
});
$('input').on('ifUnchecked', function (event) {
    $(this).closest("input").attr('checked', false);
});
```

After this you can easily find your original checkbox's state.
I wrote this code for using `icheck` in `gridView` and accessed its state from server side by C#.

Simply find your checkBox from its **id**.

Comment: this is what I was missing from iCheck all the time! Thank you.

Comment: I would consider to specify the selector to: input[type=checkbox],input[type=radio]

Answer (score 5):

Use this code for iCheck:

```
$('.i-checks').iCheck({
    checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-green',
    radioClass: 'iradio_square-green',
}).on('ifChanged', function(e) {
    // Get the field name
    var isChecked = e.currentTarget.checked;

    if (isChecked == true) {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Call

```
element.iCheck('update');
```

To get the updated markup on the element

Answer (score 3):

Use following code to check if iCheck is checked or not using single method.

```
$('Selector').on('ifChanged', function(event){

    //Check if checkbox is checked or not
    var checkboxChecked = $(this).is(':checked');

    if(checkboxChecked) {
        alert("checked");
    }else{
        alert("un-checked");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If any one have any interest on multiple **icheck()**. Then you can go for it with the below one:

```
$("#mother_checkbox").on("ifChanged", function(){
        if($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $('.child_checkbox').prop('checked', true);
            $('.child_checkbox').iCheck('update');
        }
        else{
            $('.child_checkbox').prop('checked', false);
            $('.child_checkbox').iCheck('update');
        }
});
```

It will Check/Uncheck all the child checkbox.
Good Day !

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input').on('ifChanged', function(event) {
             if($(".checkbox").is(":checked")) {
                $value = $(this).val();
             }

             else if($(".checkbox").is(":not(:checked)")) {
                $value= $(this).val();
             }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this method:

```
$(document).on('ifChanged','SELECTOR', function(event){
  alert(event.type + ' callback');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

this works for me... try it

```js
// Check #x
$( "#x" ).prop( "checked", true );
 
// Uncheck #x
$( "#x" ).prop( "checked", false );
```

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap all your checkboxes in a parent class and check the length of `.checked`..

```
if( $('.your-parent-class').find('.checked').length ){
  $(".hide").toggle();
}
```