# Check which checkboxes is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2204250/check-if-checkbox-is-checked-with-jquery) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660323/jquery-checkboxes-and-ischecked) and others but i didnt get it to work in my code.

here is the [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/dzadLkf9/1/) for better see my code on live.

this is my js

```
 //////first code to try////
 if ($('input.chek').is(':checked')) {
      $('.check-addon').css('background-color','green');
   }

  //////second code///////
var boxes = $('input[class="chek"]:checked');
       $(boxes).each(function(){
       $('.check-addon').css('background-color','green');
 });
```

this is my html

```
   <div class="inline-container"><div class="checkboxes" >
        <span class="check-addon"><input id="id1" class="chek" type="checkbox" value="1" name="id1">title1</span>
        <span class="check-addon"><input id="id2" type="checkbox" class="chek" value="1" name="id2">title2</span>
        <span class="check-addon"><input id="id3" type="checkbox" class="chek" value="1" name="id3">title3</span>
   </div></div>
```

i dont know what im doing wrong here . **i couldnt get the background Green Of the checked box in my code.**

any help would much apreciated.

**EDIT**
even the answers down works in fiddle But i  guess i have more problem here.

if i write html code above Normal , the js code is fired and works But im using html code inside js function like that:

```
  function houses(){
            var x ='<div class="inline-container"><div class="checkboxes" >
        <span class="check-addon"><input id="id1" class="chek" type="checkbox" value="1" name="id1">title1</span>
        <span class="check-addon"><input id="id2" type="checkbox" class="chek" value="1" name="id2">title2</span>
        <span class="check-addon"><input id="id3" type="checkbox" class="chek" value="1" name="id3">title3</span>
   </div></div>';
   return x ;
  }
```

so this function when i call it it works but when i want apply the above code on it its not working and not firing at all.

this function is Out of the Dom handler. [**Fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/dzadLkf9/7/)

Comment: Did you read these posts attentively? I don't see any `click` or `change` event handlers in your code. Just the code, that is executed on window loaded.

Comment: Just for downvoters, i dont know if my post is not clear or what , i have provided everything, i can improve my question instead of downvoting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind the input with a on change event

```
$('.chek').on('change', function () {
    $(this).closest('.check-addon').css('background-color',this.checked?'green':'none');
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/dzadLkf9/3/)

**Update**

You need to use event-delegation on dynamically added elements

```
$(document).on('change','.chek',function(){
    $(this).closest('.check-addon').css('background-color',this.checked?'green':'none');
});
```

Comment: your demo works but not with me i dont know whats wrong!

Comment: Are you using a DOM-ready-handler? `$(function(){/*the code*/});` @KarimDaraf

Comment: @KarimDaraf Also are you getting any errors in your console?

Comment: yes im using this `$(document).ready(function(){` and your code is inside it, and i have no error in the console. i have tried alert(1) inside your code but is not fired even.

Comment: Is the elements class `.chek` in your code? or is it `.check`?

Comment: its chek , i have double checked everything.

Comment: @KarimDaraf Can you post all your code in jsfiddle. Is jQuery included correctly? Post everything from `<html>....</html>`

Comment: Ah i have one thing i guess the problem is comming from it , i will edit and show the trouble code.

Comment: @KarimDaraf You need to use event-delegation for dynamically added elements, check my update.

Comment: Well i didnt know about delegation Now it works when checked But when unchecked it stays Green , its not none as you done.

Comment: hahaha silly ask, i have putted color and works , there is no none color as you done :). Thanks so much it works now :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to do like this :

### 1st Way:

```
$(".chek").change(function () { // will fire when checkbox checked or unchecked

    if (this.checked) // check if it is checked
         $(this).closest(".check-addon").css('background-color', 'green'); //find parent span and add css
    else
    $(this).closest(".check-addon").css('background-color','transparent');

})
```

### FIDDLE:

http://jsfiddle.net/2u697b57

### 2nd Way:

More better approach is to create a css class and add/remove it on check/uncheck:

### CSS:

```
.green
{
background-color:green;
}
```

### JQUERY:

```
$(".chek").change(function () {

    if (this.checked) 
        $(this).closest(".check-addon").addClass("green");
    else
        $(this).closest(".check-addon").removeClass("green");
```

### FIDDLE:

http://jsfiddle.net/2u697b57/1/

Comment: have done alert(1); inside but this alert is not fired even. i have checked the right everything .

Comment: put the code in _document.ready_ and make sure jquery library is included

Answer (score 0):

You need to use click/change event to detect the changes on checkboxes. Use:

```
$('input').change(function(){
 if (this.checked) 
  $(this).parent().css('background-color','green');
 else
  $(this).parent().css('background-color','none');
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4g557xke/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
$("input:checkbox").on("change", function(){
    if($(this).prop("checked")){
        $(this).parent(".check-addon").css('background-color','green');
        }
    else{
        $(this).parent(".check-addon").css('background-color','white');
    }
});
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/dzadLkf9/6/)