# JQuery hide\show if checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, checkbox

I want to make a table where row hide\show depending on if checkbox in the header is checked or not.
My script:

```
<script contextmenu="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#ShowPersonalDataList").change(function () {
        if($(this).is("checked")){
            $(".PersonalDataInset").Show;
            return
        } else
            $(".PersonalDataInset").hide;
    });

});
```

My HTML :

```
<div id="CheckBoxTables">
    <table class="CBTable">
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ColumnsNeeded.PersonalDataPartBool)
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.ColumnsNeeded.PersonalDataPartBool, new { id = "ShowPersonalDataList" })
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="PersonalDataInset">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ColumnsNeeded.FirstNameBool)
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.ColumnsNeeded.FirstNameBool)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="PersonalDataInset">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ColumnsNeeded.LastNameBool)
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.ColumnsNeeded.LastNameBool)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="PersonalDataInset">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ColumnsNeeded.AppointmentBool)
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.ColumnsNeeded.AppointmentBool)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="PersonalDataInset">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ColumnsNeeded.DivisionBool)
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.ColumnsNeeded.DivisionBool)
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

I have tried solutions from:

[jQuery if checkbox is checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7960208/jquery-if-checkbox-is-checked)

[jQuery, checkboxes and .is(":checked")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660323/jquery-checkboxes-and-ischecked)

[How to check whether a checkbox is checked in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901712/how-to-check-if-a-checkbox-is-checked-in-jquery)

But unfortunately they don't work for me, i don't know why.

Comment: `show` is a method, call it with parenthesis... => `jQuery.show()`

Comment: It should be `$(this).is(":checked")` better use `this.checked`, You just need to use `$("#ShowPersonalDataList").change(function () {
        $(".PersonalDataInset").toogle(this.checked);
    });`

Comment: To check the `checked` state, go with `this.checked`...

Comment: @Satpal just want to clarify what is wrong with `$(this).is(":checked")` is not the same as `this.checked` just the other is jQuery and the other is plain?

Comment: @guradio, Its simple and When native object is providing you the required data, Why do you need to create a jQuery object using `$(this)` then invoking the method

Comment: @Rayon Now i feel like i am retarded, ty)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a wrong selector to identify state of element as checked/unchecked. you can use `this.checked` to get checked state and use it as argument to `.toggle()`:

```
$("#ShowPersonalDataList").change(function () {
   $(".PersonalDataInset").toggle(this.checked);
});
```