# post certain value for each checked and unchecked checkbox

Tags: jquery, html, arrays, checkbox

I have a group of checkbox controls that I want to post a certain value for the checked one and null for the unchecked ones in an array

I wrote the code snippet below but i always get the same value for all regardless their checked state

```js
$("#bt1").click(function() {
  var checked = []
  var val = ''
  var $chbx = $("input[name='advsrc']")
  $chbx.each(function() {
    if ($chbx.is(':checked')) {
      val = 'ahmad'
    } else {
      val = 'null'
    }
    checked.push(val);
  });
  console.log(checked)

  return false;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="bt1" type="button" value="button" />
<input id="grndsrc" type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="advsrc" />
<input id="fnamesrc" type="checkbox" name="advsrc" />
<input id="lnamesrc" type="checkbox" name="advsrc" />
<input id="dobsrc" type="checkbox" name="advsrc" />
<input id="telsrc" type="checkbox" name="advsrc" />
<input id="ssnsrc" type="checkbox" name="advsrc" />
```

@techlove's answer

```js
$("#bt1").click(function() {
  var checked = []
  var val = ''
  var $chbx = $("input[name='advsrc']")
  $chbx.each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr("checked")) {
      val = 'ahmad'
    } else {
      val = 'null'
    }
    checked.push(val);
  });
  console.log(checked)

  return false;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="bt1" type="button" value="button" />

<input id="grndsrc" type="checkbox" name="advsrc" />
<input id="fnamesrc" type="checkbox" name="advsrc" />
<input id="lnamesrc" type="checkbox" name="advsrc" />
<input id="dobsrc" type="checkbox" name="advsrc" />
<input id="telsrc" type="checkbox" name="advsrc" />
<input id="ssnsrc" type="checkbox" name="advsrc" />
```

Comment: use if ($(this).attr("checked")). Here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660323/jquery-checkboxes-and-ischecked

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response, did not work

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/6v0f9ogq/ working fiddle

Comment: sorry, button does not fire

Comment: You'll need to demonstrate what about @techLove's suggestion doesn't work. In his code, the button, when clicked, fires, and the console logs the appropriate array.

Comment: thank you, if you go to his link and fire the button nothing happens,,, https://jsfiddle.net/6v0f9ogq/,,,, i posted his code here too,,, all are null regardless their checked state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is in this line:

```
if ($chbx.is(':checked')) {
```

Change that line to:

`if ($(this).is(':checked')) {`

Instead of [.each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/) you can use [.map()](https://api.jquery.com/map/) or [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=control) in order to achieve the desired result. Remember to use [.get()](https://api.jquery.com/get/#get2) to retrieve the elements matched by **$(":checkbox[name='advsrc']")**.

```js
$("#bt1").click(function() {
    var checked = $(":checkbox[name='advsrc']").map(function(idx, ele) {
        return (ele.checked) ? 'ahmad' : 'null';
    }).get();
    console.log(checked);

    return false;
})

$("#bt2").click(function() {
    var checked = $(":checkbox[name='advsrc']").get().reduce(function(acc, ele, idx) {
        acc[ele.id || 'noId' + idx] = (ele.checked) ? 'a' : '';
        return acc;
    }, {});
    console.log(checked);

    return false;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input id="bt1" type="button" value="button" />
<input id="bt2" type="button" value="buttonNew" />
<input id="grndsrc" type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="advsrc" />
<input id="fnamesrc" type="checkbox" name="advsrc" />
<input id="lnamesrc" type="checkbox" name="advsrc" />
<input id="dobsrc" type="checkbox" name="advsrc" />
<input id="telsrc" type="checkbox" name="advsrc" />
<input id="ssnsrc" type="checkbox" name="advsrc" />
<input  type="checkbox" name="advsrc" />
```

Comment: how can i return the ele id along with the 'ahmad' value?

Comment: @AhmadAbuMaizar you may build an array of objects: id + value

Comment: thank you so much gaetanoM,,,, @techlove's thanks too

Comment: @AhmadAbuMaizar You are wellcome

Comment: sorry gaetanoM, I cant get rid of the constant "id" and val,,, i want my array like this,,,, {"grndsrc":"a","fnamesrc":"","SnameSrctxt":"","TnameSrctxt":"","LnameSrctxt":"","TelSrcTxt":"","SSNSrcTxt":"","EmailSrctxt":"","DOBSrcTxt":""}

Comment: I really appreciate it gaetanoM,,, where can i read more about this function,,, I m not a programmer but I kind of learning on my own and of course from you guys here

Comment: You may take a tour on stackoverflow for documentation. Click on the tag JavaScript or jQuery for instance.