# Getting value using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have 2 input types which are both check boxes.
I am trying to get the value of them but it says it is 'undefined'.

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <input type='checkbox' class='gymyears'>
    Yes
    <input type='checkbox' class='gymyears'>
    No
  </td>
</tr>

var Gymyearsv = $(".gymyears").val();
```

Comment: Your checkbox input fields do not _have_ a value.

Comment: Why you don't use type="radio" ... if you select checkbox the user can check both, YES and NO... Using radio the user has to select just one... or YES or NO

Comment: And you can check if checked like this $(".gymyears").is(':checked')

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery, checkboxes and .is(":checked")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660323/jquery-checkboxes-and-ischecked)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=get+value+from+checkbox

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check whether a checkbox is checked in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901712/how-to-check-whether-a-checkbox-is-checked-in-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your checkboxes have'nt a value, thats why its still undefined. You have to look for 'checked' instead:

```js
var Gymyearsv = $(".gymyears");

function getState() {
  Gymyearsv.each(function(i, checkbox) {
    console.log(checkbox.checked);
  });
}

// or use $('#yourID').is(":checked");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
  <td>
    <input type='checkbox' class='gymyears'> Yes
    <input type='checkbox' class='gymyears'> No
  </td>
</tr>
<button onclick="getState();">get state</button>
```

Or as Roy mentioned you could use radios instead:

```js
function getState(){
  console.log($("input[name=gymyears]:checked").val());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
  <td>
    <input type='radio' name='gymyears' value="yes"> Yes
    <input type='radio' name='gymyears' value="no"> No
  </td>
</tr>
<button onclick="getState();">get state</button>
```